# Which is the best way to test my Magento system after developed

Tags: magento-1.9, testing, unit-tests, workflow

I just recently develop Magento system for personal use.

I want to know about how to test my Magento system.

Want to know about some tools or testing flow.

Comment: What exactly would you like to test? Would you like to set up some automatic tests?

Comment: i want to test full system 

i don't how to do it manually or automatic

Comment: Have you checked https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Magento+Automated+Testing+Guide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

step:1:- I wish to clear up the database so I can start over again. This means doing the following:

```
Clearing all products
Clearing all attributes
Clearing all attribute sets
Clearing all categories
Clearing all orders, shipments, transactions etc.
```

I always like to create a freshly copied test or development instance of the site.  I use the development site to test out any new code, style, or configuration changes before applying them to the production server. Better safe than sorry, right?

I used to create the test instance as a subdomain on the production server.  However, that approach can lead to easy mistakes, at least in my experience.

Comment: and visit link:-http://mcamaterialany.blogspot.in/2015/07/create-test-instance-of-magento-store.html